# Itead Sonoff RF WiFi & 433MHz switch: Identifying an unknown chip on the 433MHz card

Tags: rf, 433mhz

I have the Sonoff RF which is a mains relay switch which is activated by either WiFi or a 433MHz remote. 
The particular Sonoff RF's I have arrived from China on 21/9/2017.
I flashed these Sonoff RF's last week with the lastest tasmota firmware. The firmware version I flashed was sonoff.bin (there are many other tasmota firmwares available).

I understand that Sonoff RF firmware for the WiFi card (which is I beleive ESP8266-01 based), and the firmware for the 433MHz card are different and seperate. This makes sense becasue a Sonoff vesion is sold without the 433MHz card. Sold without the 433MHz card it is called the Sonoff Basic.

So by flashing new firmware to the ESP8266-01 card the 433MHz card is unaffected.

This I have confirmed through use of the 433MHz card since flashing the tasmota firmware: the 433MHz card behaves in the same way as it did with the original OEM Itead firmware. In any case the author of the tasmota firmware states that his firmware has no impact on the 433 MHz card.

I am interested in the 433MHz card becasue I beleive it could have a better firmware.

Currently a 433MHz remote paired with the card can only toggle the relay  switch.
For more useful functionality the remote needs to be able to set the switch to OFF or ON as well as having TOGGLE functionallity.

As part of my initial investigations of this card, I am trying to identify the chips on the card. I've used Google quite extensively with no luck in regard to one of the chips, so am wandering if anyone on here has some working knowledge of such a chip arrangement.

Below is a picture of what I call the front of the card

[image: Front of card showing The SYN470R 1631 chip]

[image: Close up of the SYN470R 1631 chip]

The picture above shows the SYN470R 1631 chip. The data sheet is here http://img.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/453934_1928180.pdf

Below is a picture of what I call the back of the card

[image: Shows an unidentified 16 pin SMD chip]

[image: Unidentified 16 pin SMD chip]

The above photo shows the can with 6.7458 stamped on.

I am unable to identify the 16 pin SMD chip, with 4 pins per side.
As far as my eyes can see the chip text reads
**BB1 0 F 2 G A  GOGA4 1620 A**,
but I may be wrong and your eyes may be better than mine.
I've googled various possible permutations of this with no success.
May be I missed something obvious.
Eg I tried 8810 instead of what looks to me like BB10, etc.

**Do you know what this chip is?**

Perhaps you can shed some light on how this 433MHz board can be programmed for ON / OFF as well as Toggle switching functionallity. If so please post up.

---

**PHOTOS ADDED BELOW IN ATTEMPT TO CLARIFY CHIP IDENTITY**

---

Below photo shows side view. Seems to show 20-pin package

[image: side view seems to show 20-pin package]

Below photo shows 5 tracks coming in from left. 4 lower down and one appears to go to the top corner pad. QFN20 has corner pads. So this potentially accords well with the package being a QFN20.

[image: Top view lookng at tracks going in to the chip]

Below is from pg 48 on datasheet linked in the answer. Shows 4 pins at edge of chip & two corner pads.

[image: From the datasheet linked in the answer]

Comment: Most likely the actual remote functions are commanded from or to the main processor, not the radio.  What you really need to do is investigate the communication channel in between, with a scope and/or logic analyzer.  Also keep in mind that there's a lot of material out there on reversing simple remote commands, and you don't necessarily need anything like the original radio to work with most OOK systems.

Comment: You _really_ don't want to use a bloody 8051 in the year 2019. Everyone but Silabs stopped using these well over 20 years ago. If you wondered what could possibly be crappier than Arduino/AVR, this is the answer. Never parts from Silabs like EFM32 have radio on-chip, use those instead.

Comment: @Lundin which is the 8051? What are you recommending; I'm no too sure from you're comment. thanks

Comment: If you don't know what an 8051 is, you should probably back away from this project right now. What I'm recommending instead was quite clear in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi @Lundin, I think this is the chip you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51 ? But I can't be certian as I am not a mind reader & it's not obvious to me how "8051" is relevant. Can you please explain. I'd be grateful. I've many years experience - broadly - in micro electronics but haven't come across the 8051. Asking for your understanding : it's a vast field.

Comment: @Kes It is a very (in)famous Intel MCU from the early 1980s, which lots of silicon vendors made their own version of. It was known as one of the least code efficient cores in the history of mankind. Even among those who didn't make their own 8051, lots were influenced by it. It goes back to the Intel vs Motorola wars and so most cores on the market from 1980s to 2000s are either heavily influenced by 8051 or by Motorola 6800. 8051 were produced until the 2000s, Phillips/NXP in particular promoting them still long after Intel had stopped producing them, but eventually NXP also stopped. ->

Comment: Some confused vendors like Silabs still use them and try to scam engineers to buy them, like this "busy bee" crap, but even Silabs favour ARM nowadays, with EFM32 being their "highly recommended" product line.

Comment: So what I'm saying is, don't specify this crap into new products. EFM32 is nice enough and Silabs is the market leader in integrated radio chips with some very good parts. I would desperately recommend to stay clear of their Eclipse nightmare "Simplicity Studio" though, it is incredibly buggy even by Eclipse standards. It is in fact perhaps the worst IDE I have ever used, and I have used some 50+ different ones over the years.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you. That's a great answer which I appreciate. I remember the Intel vs Motorola wars. Loong time ago. I'd forgotten though. I was on the fabrication side in electron lithography, so never got to really consider cores other than the ones I was trying to fabricate onto substrate which were all unique with daft stuff like optical wageguides and electronics on the same substrate ! It explains my broader ignorance. This is a home project. I hope the post will help folks who want to re-engineer the poor firmware on the 8051 chip which is not tremendously useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QFN Package is the [BB10-F2G](https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/EFM8BB1-DataSheet-958779.pdf) microcontroller from silicon labs. The other chip, as you've identified, is just an ASK receiver. The microcontroller is decoding the output into commands. It doesn't really seem like there's anything else on the card. The crystal is there to allow accurate timing for decoding the radio signal.

You can probably reprogram this chip using the [Simplicity Studio](https://www.silabs.com/support/getting-started/microcontrollers/efm8-mcu) tool.

Comment: Something does not quite add up when looking at the data sheet that you linked. The BB10-F2G part would be a 20-pin QFN package as per the Product Selection Guide. However the part in the OPs photo really looks more like a 16-pin QFN package. SiLabs offering of this part with 16 pins is a SOIC16. Could it be a clone chip or a special order device in non-standard package?

Comment: I though the chip had pins sticking out of it. Looking more closely at the photo,   now I'm not sure. Are they pins, are they not? Is it a solder bump chip with 20 pins & some of them are not used ... Here is a possible QFN20 https://uk.rs-online.com/web/cp/1690180,8656263/?sra=p

Comment: According to the datasheet link @BeB00 has posted  
`BB1`=Busy Bee 1 Family, 
`0`=Family Feature Set, 
`F`=Memory type is Flash, 
`2`=Flash memory size is 2KB, 
`G`=Temperature Grade is -40 to +85,
`A`=Chip Revision. 
Dataseet document does not seem to explain `GOGA4`. 
`1620 A` is a date of manufacture & revision code. `16` is year 2016. `20` is week 20. `A` is the device revision

Comment: The meaning of `GOGA4` or is it `QOGA4` (I can't quite see it) remains a mystery to me.

Comment: That's just some internal batch tracing stuff

Comment: @MichaelKaras It's a QFN20, there will be 4 pads below the part, one in each corner, which you can't see from above.